# Can we equate SHM with motion in a circle?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, angular-velocity

So in SHM, $v = r\omega\cos\omega t$. But we also know that $v = r\omega$ from circular motion. Then, we can write
$$r\omega = r\omega\cos \omega t$$
$$1 = \cos\omega t \tag{1} \label{1}$$
$$0 = \omega t \tag{2} \label{2}$$
Equation $\ref{2}$ comes from equation $\ref{1}$. Then from $\ref{2}$, $\omega$ should always be $0$ no matter the time period. Is this correct?

Comment: Please use descriptive titles. Nobody has any hint about the content of the question with this title.

Comment: Voting to reopen. I have improved the title, and this is a perfectly clear question with a straightforward answer.

Comment: Incidentally as gandalf has noted in their answer, you can project the circular motion along perpendicular axes and get SHM. I don't remember what site I saw it on but there are nice visualizations of exactly what is mentioned.

Comment: Where did you get eq (i) from $(1 = cos(\omega t) )$ ? It is obviously not generally true because it is  varying with time, unless $\omega$ is constantly varying in just the right way. I think you need to clear that one up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For circular motion in the plane the position is written as:
$$\vec r(t)=r\cos(\omega t)\mathbf{\hat x}+r\sin(\omega t)\mathbf{\hat y}.$$
Taking the time derivative we get the velocity:
$$\vec v(t)=-r\omega\sin(\omega t)\mathbf{\hat x}+r\omega\cos(\omega t)\mathbf{\hat y}.$$
If we calculate the magnitude of the velocity we get:
$$|\vec v(t)|=\sqrt{r^2\omega^2(\sin t^2(\omega t)+\cos^2(\omega t)}=r\omega.$$
Thus, the relation $v=r\omega$ takes into account both components of the velocity in circular motion, on the other hand, $v_x=-r\omega\sin(\omega t)$ is only the x-component of the velocity. So, the relation $r\omega=-r\omega\sin(\omega t)$ does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the following correct ?

No. You are trying to equate two different motions - SHM, which is a one-dimensional motion with varying speed, and circular motion, which is a  two dimensional motion at constant speed. This is just nonsense.

However, there *is* a connection between the two motions. If an object goes round a circle at constant speed $v$ then the projection of its motion along a diameter of the circle executes SHM. And if its position along one diameter is $x = r \sin (\omega t)$ then its velocity along that diameter is $v_x = r \omega \cos (\omega t)$. Similarly, its velocity along the perpendicular diameter is $v_y = r \omega \sin (\omega t)$ and so its speed (in two dimensions) is

$v = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2} = r \omega$

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to equate SHM with motion in a circle. If we attach a particle to one end of a massless rod of length R and attach the other end of the rod to a pivot, then if the particle is rotating with constant angular velocity $\omega$ then the magnitude (s) of the instantaneous tangential velocity is given by $$s = R \omega$$.

Lets say we are looking from above where we see the circle formed by the motion. Now look from the side. The particle seems to accelerate from one side until it gets to the middle, then decelerates until it comes to a stop a distance R from the centre and then accelerate back towards the centre. The velocity of the particle as a function of time from this point of view is simply $$v(t) = \omega R \cos (\omega t)$$ if we set t=0 when the particle is passing the centre at maximum speed.

in other words SHM is simply circular motion looked at from a different angle.

Hover, it is important to note that the equation for the magnitude of the instantaneous tangential velocity $$|V_{tangential}| = R \omega $$ is only valid when looking at the motion from above the axis of rotation where the tangential speed is constant if $\omega$ is constant.